# Question on derivation of Schrödinger's equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

I have recently started reading Nanoscale Physics for Materials Science by Tsurumi et al. and the authors present a unique derivation of Schrödinger's equation in the first chapter:

I was wondering how equation 1.32 is derived from 1.31, 1.29, and 1.27. More specifically, how does the $-2m(E-V)/(h^2v^2)$ term come about in equation 1.32?

[image: 1.23 to 1.29]

[image: 1.30 to 1.32]

Comment: I believe in eq. (1.29) it should be  $\frac{1}{s^2}$ rather than $\frac{1}{\nu^2}$. The term you are asking about is then a direct substitution from eq.(1.27)

Comment: @BySymmetry that was my thought exactly, but I guess I will have to reach out to the author for more clarification? I appreciate your response.